# Save and Retrieve realm data from Fragment life cycle?

Tags: android, realm

I have created an `Activity` which hosts a `ViewPager` with four `Fragment`. I am trying to load user data from `realm` in each different `fragment`. I want to save user data while the `tab` or `Fragment` is being switched.
I am loading the data in `@AfterViews` or `onViewCreated`. Trying to save the data in `onDestroyView` in `executeTransactionAsync`.

**Problem** While trying to switch the `tab`, the `tab indicator` slides very slowly with a pause. If I remove the code `executeTransactionAsync` from `onDestroyView` then the `tab indicator` slides smoothly.

What I would like to see is `tab indicator` sliding slowing while trying to switch between fragments.

**Update 1** `onDestroy`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
Timber.d("onDestroy() called");
super.onDestroy();

// Do not send event after activity or fragment has been destroyed
mCompositeDisposable.clear();
RefWatcher refWatcher = 
MyApplication.getRefWatcher(getActivity());
refWatcher.watch(this);
}
```

Comment: You display this data in your fragment?

Comment: @RodrigoGontijo I display this data in Fragment within ViewPager.

Comment: Post your onDestroy and any other relevant code, please.

Comment: @MateusGondim updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to put your executeTransactionAsync inside onPause() and onResume() fragment methods?

Comment: I am loading data in onViewCreated and saving in onDestroyView

Comment: try to change it to the methods i suggested

Comment: I will let you know if it helps. Thank-you

Comment: Sliding was slow because of the third party library that I was using.  com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1. However I am now saving the data in onPause() and I did a silly mistake in hurry. Thanks and up voting your answer.